# Magento 2 knockout js use JSON array inside JSON object

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs, json

Js Code :

```
getRowData: function() {
                    return  window.checkoutConfig.row_data;
                }
```

Knockout Code :

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: getRowData(), as: 'rowdata' } -->
                <p data-bind="rowdata.rows.item"></p>// here i need rows key dynamic then how could i get it.
            <!-- /ko -->
```

I am facing some challenges to render this type of data in magento checkout page using knockout js.

```
{
"rows":[
     {"Item":2,"Odd or Even":"number 2 is even"}
],
"rows2":[
     {"Item":2,"Odd or Even":"number 2 is even"}
],
}
```

**"rows"**  it will be dynamic and i am facing issue to get data by passing row key as dynamic in knockout js.

**For example on checkout :** I want to display row of Item value how could i get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make the frontend update dynamically you'll need to store the data as a KO observable like so:

```
getRowData: function() {
    return  ko.observable(window.checkoutConfig.row_data);
}
```

And how you render it depends on what you need to show, something like this should work:

```
<p data-bind="text: rowdata.rows.item['Odd or Even']"></p>
```

I recommend not using spaces in properties, `oddOrEven` would be slighty easier to work with.

Comment: How could be the [rows] key can be used dynamically. As like we use foreach in php as a key value pair.